# Is minus (negative) zero equivalent to 0 in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very basic MySQL query that reads rows from a database table and adds or subtracts the row value to a PHP string defined as $total_balance.

For example;

```
$statement_details_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT transaction_nominal_code, SUM(transaction_debit) as TotalDebit, SUM(transaction_credit) as TotalCredit FROM accounts_transaction GROUP BY transaction_nominal_code") or die(mysql_error());

while($statement_details = mysqli_fetch_array( $statement_details_query )) {

$balance = $statement_details['TotalCredit'] - $statement_details['TotalDebit'];

$total_balance = $total_balance + $balance;

}

echo number_format($total_balance, 2, '.', ',');
```

My question is, what is the difference between -0 and 0?

Comment: Zero can't be negative!!

Comment: Yes it can. It is called signed zero, and it is an important part of floating point numbers.

Comment: The balance is always Debit minus Credit.

Comment: how is related the code shown to the question asked?  do you have an -0 echoed?

Comment: Yes, I have a -0 echoed

Comment: Why does `number_format` echo `-0` instead of `-0.00` or `0.00`? Are you sure you posted the right code? The `-` could be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, it does echo -0.00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP, there is no real difference:

Float:

```
php > $negZ = -0.0;
php > $posZ = +0.0;
php > var_dump($negZ == $posZ, $negZ === $posZ);
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Int:

```
php > $negZ = -0;
php > $posZ = +0;
php > var_dump($negZ == $posZ, $negZ === $posZ);
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Comment: Why 'no real'? Is there a difference or not? To me, it seems as if there is no difference at all.

Comment: because yes, under IEEE 754, there are positive and negative zeroes. php glosses that over and just treats all zeroes as zero.

Comment: I know IEEE 754. My question was how PHP does make sure that `-0 === +0` is true.

Comment: Here's a real difference: as negative zero float was not known in PHP 5, you can get unexpected issues when migrating from 5 to 7. I just fixed a bug in some old jpgraph version (php graph library) where the precision in a format string was calculated to be "-0" which was subsequently used in a format string, which became "%01.-0f" which is invalid, and will result in the string "0f" always.

Answer (score 2):

I just asked myself the same question and thought 0 === -0 is true:

[image: -1]

[image: true]

How to reproduce:

```
<?php

$sum = 1.0000001;
$val = 1.00;

$a = round($val - $sum,2);
var_dump($a, $a === 0);
```

> float(-0)
>   bool(false)

Comment: it's because `round` returns `float`, not `int`

Answer (score 2):

```
php > echo bin2hex(pack("f", 0.0));
00000000
php > echo bin2hex(pack("f", +0.0));
00000000
php > echo bin2hex(pack("f", -0.0));
00000080

php > var_dump(unpack("f", "\x00\x00\x00\x00")[1]);
float(0)
php > var_dump(unpack("f", "\x00\x00\x00\x80")[1]);
float(-0)
```

Comment: I think you should summarize your answer, instead of forcing people to read the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but stumbled upon an issue with this today.

```
if (is_numeric($denominator) && $denominator) {
    return 10 / $denominator;
}
```

If $denominator is negative zero this will result in a division by zero. So it looks like -0 == true which might be perfectly fine. Just not what I expected...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 0 == -0.

See my test below:
http://viper-7.com/pa0xBU

Comment: `-0` is treated as `0` in PHP. Problem actually relates **floats**