# PHP -0 is not <=0

Tags: php, function, if-statement, return-value, php-7

Within a *function X* I am using the return value of another *function Y*. This Y sometimes returns the value `-0`. I am not able to catch this value with the following code:

```
if($y <= 0){
    return 'foo';
}else{
    return $y;
}
```

This should trigger the `return 'foo'` but this is not happening and I don't know why. `gettype($y)` returns *double*. Any explanations and/or solutions to catch this special case? `int($y)` doesn't do the trick.

**Edit:** The reference to [Question 31250241](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250241) does not help. They claim that the values are the same. But I can reproduce that on my 7.0.11 install this is not the case. I have just tested on a 7.0.20 and there it appears to be equal. This might be a PHP bug or something special in my 7.0.11 setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is minus (negative) zero equivalent to 0 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250241/is-minus-negative-zero-equivalent-to-0-in-php)

Comment: Works for me, PHP 7.0.18, with `$y = -0.0; if ($y <= 0) { echo "Y"; } else { echo "N"; }`.

Comment: Why the close votes? Apparently there's a problem, just seemingly not the one OP thinks of initially.

Comment: `var_dump(-0 <= 0);` correctly returns `bool(true)` on PHP 7.0.20 and 5.6.30.  What version are you using?

Comment: It works as you expect: See [fiddle](https://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$y%20=%20-0;%5Cnif%20($y%20%3C=%200)%20%7B%5Cn%20echo%20%27foo%27;%5Cn%7D%20else%20%7B%5Cn%20echo%20%27bar%27;%5Cn%7D%5Cn?%3E)

Comment: What does `var_dump($y)` output ?

Comment: `var_dump($y)` returns `float(-0)`